# There is a typo in my data, how do I fix it so I can join two tables correctly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

So, I have a bit of an unusual problem. I have two tables I need to join. Here is a sample of both of them:

[image: Table1]

[image]

I want to join the columns DATE, SITA, B, C, Capacity, SEGMENT (From the first table) with the columns datearrived, sita, B, C, Rooms, Market_segment (from the second table).

Now, my big issue is that there is a typo in the first table in the column segment: BAO should be BOA. As a result any data entry with BAO doesn't get matched to BOA in the second table and thus I am missing data when I do the join.

What can I do to fix this? Is there something i can do in the join query so that sql treats BAO and BOA as the same thing?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT t1.DATE, t1.SITA, t1.B, t1.C, t1.Capacity, t1.REV, t1.RNS, t1.SEGMENT, t2.Rn, t2.Rev
FROM t1
JOIN t2
ON T1.B = t2.B and t1.C = t2.C and t1.Capacity = t2.Rooms and t1.SEGMENT = t2.Market_segment
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why can't you simply use an update statement? Update YourTable set YourColumn = 'BOA' where YourColumn = 'BAO'

Comment: Simply use the replace function in the ON condition of the join and replace the wrong entry if you are not able to change the data.

Comment: How important is performance?

Comment: In the join condition how? Would it go after all the join conditions? @Bave

Comment: What do you mean by performance?@GordonLinoff

Comment: Please share your query which you have built.

Comment: ... INNER JOIN secTable st ON st.YourColumn = REPLACE(primary.YourColumn, 'BAO', 'BOA') i meant like this.

Comment: @HatimStovewala i have added my query

Comment: @Sorath Added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT t1.DATE, t1.SITA, t1.B, t1.C, t1.Capacity, t1.REV, t1.RNS, REPLACE(t1.SEGMENT,'BAO','BOA'), t2.Rn, t2.Rev
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON T1.B = t2.B and t1.C = t2.C and t1.Capacity = t2.Rooms and REPLACE(t1.SEGMENT,'BAO','BOA') = t2.Market_segment;
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Works, assuming values are no more than three characters. If longer, you'd have problems with (say) `TBAO` being turned into `TBOA`...

Answer (score 1):

Use this and replace table with the name of your table:

```
UPDATE table SET Market_segment = 'BOA' WHERE Market_segment = 'BAO';
```

Then use join to join the tables.

Comment: I don't have permission to update tables, so would like to do it within my query!

Comment: No, really. Once you start putting in hard-coded fixes for bad data, when does it stop? You could end up having to replace a dozen "bad data" values by the end of the year. Don't do it!

Comment: Another argument: Your query is good, but the data is bad. The data must be fixed, or this query **and every other query hitting this database** will have to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

In your JOIN ON clause or your WHERE clause (wherever your are defining the conditions of the join) you can specify:

```
table1.Segment = table2.Market_segment
or (table1.Segment = 'BAO' and table2.Market_segement = 'BOA')
```